# Generate all possible alternative strings based on a dictionary node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm not a coder and I'm trying to get a freelancer to understand my needs. So this question may be simple.

I have a list of automotive parts and would like to generate their alternative descriptions based on a predefined list.

ie.

"**LH** FENDER" is in my DB

I want to generate alternative descriptions by the following list.

"LHF","LEFT HAND FRONT","**LH**","LEFT HAND","PINK"

RESULT:

LH FENDER
LHF FENDER
LEFT HAND FRONT FENDER
LEFT HAND FENDER
PINK FENDER

There is 500,000 different items in my DB that may or may not contain words that need to be substituted.
Also please note that the replacement must be of whole words within the description.

Comment: I think you can explain it that way to your freelancer, but I didn't see any real question in your post isn't it? How can we help ?

Comment: How can it be done? He has said he cannot do it.

Comment: It's a quite easy problem, I answered with a suggestion. By the way if you are looking for a new freelance developer feel free to contact me  !

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easily doable I think. For example:

```js
const data = "LH FENDER";

const replacements = [
  "LHF", "LEFT HAND FRONT", "LH", "LEFT HAND", "PINK"
];

const to_replace = data.split(" ").find(w => replacements.includes(w));

const result = replacements.map(r => data.replace(to_replace, r));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The issue is the const data. It could be any one within the list.

Comment: @John-CarlosElKhouri Of course, this is just to illustrate the example. A real life use case would be a generalization of this, a function working for any data matched with any keyword list...

Comment: Can I please get your details

Comment: @John-CarlosElKhouri You can contact me on LinkedIn https://linkedin.com/mwlite/in/pierre-jarriges .